# Estimating $\int_0^1\sin(x^2)dx$ using the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, estimation

**Problem:**

a) Find the Taylor polynomial $T_6(x)$ for $f(x) = \sin(x)$ about $x=0$.

I found this to be $x-\frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} + O(x^6)$.

b) Use this to estimate $\int_0^1\sin(x^2)dx$ with an error less than $0.00002$.

This is where I hit the wall.

**Question:**

How can I use the Taylor polynomial for a (slightly) different function, and how can I tell when I've come within a certain range of the analytical answer?

**Update:**

Since $f(x)$ and all its derivatives are continuous on the interval $[0,1]$, I may use that the error $|R_6(x^2)| \leq \frac M{7!}\int_0^1x^6dx = \frac{M}{7\cdot7!}$, if I haven't made any mistakes. Now I need to find an $M$ which satisfies $M\geq |f^{(7)}(x)$ on the interval. Do I need to find the 7th derivative of $\sin(x^2)$ for this, or may I use the 7th derivative of $\sin(x)$ somehow?

Comment: Substitute $x^2$ for $x$ and try to find an expression for the general term

Comment: You can bound the error of your Taylor polynomial at values between 0 and 1. You can then bound the cumulative error, namely the error of the integral, on the interval $[0, 1]$. Se https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder .

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret - Thanks! I've made some progress - hopefully in the right directions - and updated my question with details and a follow-up question. Would you mind giving it a look?

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be well on your way, I provide to you the Taylor expansion:

$$\sin(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4n-2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

By Taylor's theorem, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n\notin\lbrace2,6,10,\dots 4n-2,\dots\rbrace$.

---

Another way to check if you have come within a certain range is to calculate the next few terms and see if they affect the value by less than your error range.  For example:

$$1+0.1+0.01+0.001+\dots\approx1.111$$

Adding the next few terms does not appear to alter the result by more than $0.001$, so $1.111$ approximates this out with an error less than $\pm0.0001$.

Never hurts to check for higher accuracy anyways.